# getting top exchange rate using sql

Tags: mysql, sql

can someone show me how to get top exchange rate cause I'm really struggling to do it for example I have a table of 20 records and has 2 money that is of USD currency 3 money that is of Euro currency 4 money that is of Peso currency 5 money that is of Japanese yen currency then get the top 5 of it when I query the table the result would be something like this

Top exchange rate:

```
   Currency         Count
   ------------    --------
   Japanese Yen       5
   Peso               4
   Euro               3
   USD                2
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT currency
      ,COUNT(*) rate
FROM rates
GROUP BY currency
ORDER BY rate DESC
LIMIT 5;
```